# How to design a "template" system using a database

Tags: postgresql, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I have an application where the users run "experiments", the experiments have a number of "subjects" and for each subject there is a "setting" (for a device that is used to research the subject).

So I basically have these tables:

```
Experiment
----------
id (PK)
name

Subject
-------
id (PK)
name
experiment_id (FK)
setting_id (FK)

Setting
-------
id (PK)
value_a
value_b
value_c
```

The relations are basically like this:

```
Experiment ---* Subject *--- Setting
```

Once the user creates a new experiment and adds a subject to experiment on, he also needs to define the settings (for a device used to research the subject).

However, instead of having the user define the settings every time, I would also like to offer a mechanism to load/save setting templates.

What would be a good database design for this?

Everything I came up with had some drawbacks:

1. Add a "SettingTemplate" table which basically has a name + the same
   colums as Setting. Then rows could just be copied. However, I think
   it's usually a not a good idea to duplicate things.
2. Add a "SettingTemplate" table which has a name and then a FK to an
   entry in the Setting table. However, that would mean that a change
   to the setting/template would directly impact ALL experiments and
   subjects around. That's something I want to avoid.

Since I think the second option is worse, I prefer the first one. However, I bet there is a better way to do this... Can you help?

Comment: Postgres supports [table inheritance](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html). Creating a common parent for `Setting` and `SettingTemplate` would let you keep the structures in sync without needing to explicitly duplicate the table definition.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about table inheritance yet. That might be useful for something like in 1).

Answer (score 3):

Why not reuse the setting table?

```
User
----
id (PK)

Setting
-------
id (PK)
user_id (FK)
setting_name
value_a
value_b
value_c
```

A user creates settings, which are saved in `setting`.

When a user is at the form to create a new Subject, give him a select box with `(setting_id, setting_name)` to chose from, and insert the selected setting_id into the subject row.

```
select id, setting_name from setting where user_id = :user_id
```

---

Update: It looks to me like you are interested in historical versioning instead.

```
Setting
-------
setting_id (PK)
setting_name

SettingVersion
--------------
setting_version_id (PK)
setting_id         (FK)
value_a
value_b
value_c

Subject
-------
id
name
experiment_id      (FK)
setting_version_id (FK)
```

All of the PK's must be incrementing Ids/sequence generated values.

When a user wants to "create a brand new setting", you must perform two inserts instead:

```
Insert a row into Setting, and grab the setting_id from this insert.
Insert a row into SettingVersion, using the setting_id from above as the FK in this table.
```

When a user wants to "edit a setting", you perform an insert instead of an update:

```
Insert a row into SettingVersion, using the setting_id from the original setting that you want to modify
```

After a user created/"modified" a setting, he can then use it in his experiment via:

```
insert a row into Subject, using the setting_version_id from the particular SettingVersion
```

Also, depending on what you want to do, you could add a `created_by` field in `Setting` to indicate which user created the original setting; add a `created_by` field in `SettingVersion` to indicate which user created the modified setting of the original; add a `setting_version_number` to indicate the order in which a variation of a particular `Setting` was created.

Comment: That might be an option. However, I would prefer "global" templates which are visible for all users.

Comment: @katzenversteher so would you create the templates for the user, and permit them to only use your template, or would you also let them create their own personal, non global templates?

Comment: My idea was to allow users to create, edit and delete global templates. Wen a template is actually used, the values of the template would be copied so nothing breaks if the template is changed afterwards.

Comment: @katzenversteher When I say `global` templates, I mean that the template is available to all users. Are you sure you want any user to be able to delete and update templates created by other users?

Comment: @katzenversteher I think you may be looking for historical versioning. I've updated my answer; take a look.

Comment: I indeed want any user to be able to delete and update templates by other users. Your historical versioning update looks pretty promising. Thank you very much!